# Docker add Javafx to openJDK

Tags: java, docker, javafx, kubernetes, containers

I have build a docker container with this command:

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        openjfx \
        unzip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_dists_*
```

but my resulting java container still does not have java fx.. as evidenced by this excpetion: 
`...[org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javafx.util.Pair not present`

I have also tried:

```
  FROM openjdk:8-jdk
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjfx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

which has not worked.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Maybe this is shortsighted on my part, but... Why would you want to do this - install a GUI SDK in a non-GUI container?
If you really need some code from javaFX, I believe you can just download the JARs using maven/gradle.

Comment: could you point me to the maven dependency that I could pyt in my pom? I

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.2</version>
</dependency> maybe?

Comment: I'd recommend checking the documentation -  https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular